# Using fseek and fread

Tags: c, io, fread, fseek

I am working on a project that reads data from bin files and processes the data. The bin file is huge and is about 150MB. I am trying to use fseek to skip unwanted processing of data.

I am wondering if the processing time of fseek is the same as fread.

Thanks!

Comment: `fseek` is supposed to be much faster then `fread` because all it does is moving a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

`fseek` just repositions the internal file pointer whereas `fread` actually reads data. So I guess `fseek` should be much faster than `fread`

If you are really curious to see what's happening behind the screen, download `glibc` from [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/) and check for yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if the processing time of `fseek` is the same as `fread`.

Probably not though, of course, it's implementation-dependent.

Most likely, `fseek` will only set an in-memory "file pointer" without going out to the disk to read any information. `fread`, on the other hand, will read information.

An `fseek` to file position 149M followed by a 1M `fread` will probably be faster than 150 different 1M `fread` calls, throwing away all but the last.

Answer (score 0):

I probably feel fseek might be bit faster than fread as fseek changes the pointer position to the new address space that you have mentioned and there is no date read is happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you are processing huge files have you considered alternatives to read/write?
You may find that mmap() (UNIX) or MapViewOfFile (Windows) is a more suitable alternative. 
The following UNIX example demonstrates opening a file for reading and counting the occurance of the ASCII character 'Q'. NOTE - all error checking has been omitted to make the example shorter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i, fd, len, total;
  char *map, *ptr;

  fd = open("/tmp/mybigfile", O_RDONLY);

  len = lseek(fd, SEEK_END, 0);

  map = (char *)mmap(0, len, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

  total = 0;
  for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
    if (map[i] == 'Q') total++;
  }

  printf("Found %d instances of 'Q'\n");

  munmap(map, len);

  close(fd);
}
```

Comment: This answer will be helpful when you add the performance figures for `mmap` when compared to plain `fread` `fseek`

Comment: The fseek() fread() operations are library calls, backed by the read() and lseek() system calls. The fstream family of function will use buffered IO to improve performance but still require the system calls to be made at some point. The mmap() call is a single system call that relies on the OS paging buffers to and from disk on your behalf. I would be suprised if you found fread() faster that using this approach.

Comment: From other posts you have made I am guessing you are processing some binary datafiles. If the data was written on the same platform with matching endianess then reading fixed sized fields in and out of the file is trivial using the mmap(). Simply overlay the structure over the location you would expect to find it in the map and read from the structure directly.

Comment: My intention was, by adding performance figures, the OP and others will be more inclined towards this approach ( you know numbers say a lot than facts :) ), and your answer will be _more_ useful.